# Can't start traning with custom data in YOLO v8

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov8

I am training with my own images in YOLO v8. I am using Windows 10/Nvidia RTX3080 Ti. I can run predict code without any problems. But when I train, the training process won't start. The program stops at "train:", and won't go on to "val:" or further.
The .yaml file is as below.
[tower_n.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFkxN.png)
I have established a conda enviroment with Python 3.11. I also installed Pytorch and cuda toolkit correctly.
[torch version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZakyQ.png)
Below is my training code and messages.
Please help me out. Thank you.

```
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt') # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
model.train(data='D:/yolo/tower_n.yaml', epochs=100, imgsz=640)
```

Messages:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn8bM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARRWv.png)

I have tried changing the model to yolov8x.pt, and tried setting workers=1, and tried setting imgsz=1280, and epochs=200. And the results are the same, the training won't start.
Could anyone help me with this problem?
Thank you!